# unable to delete the orphan record after once handling a roll back exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, rollback

i am trying to delete the actor record from the actor table of which some actors are mapped to one or more films from the film table.When i was trying to delete an actor record which is not mapped to any film, it was getting removed.But when i tried to remove an actor record which is not mapped to any film after i handled a roll back exception(trying to delete an actor which is mapped to film) it was not getting deleted it was also handled why?

```
public boolean RemoveActor(Actor actor){
        try
        {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.remove(actor);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            return true;
        }
        catch(RollbackException e)
        {
            System.out.println("fyufyuff");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You should be calling `em.getTransaction().rollback()` in the `catch` clause.  If the delete never took place, then you might need to roll anything back.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i am getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active